# Помогите определить кодировку API (php)

Tags: php, xml

Здравствуйте. Получаю от сервера такой ответ, но хотелось бы привести его в читаемый вариант, что это может быть? Вроде, как base64. Помогите разобраться в кодировке.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>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</root>
```

Comment: а что дожна обозначать метка [tag:gate]? приведённая строка — скорее всего, какой-то хэш от каких-то данных.

Comment: Может документацию сервиса почитать? Что, кто, зачем - непонятно. Откуда взялась эта строчка? Ты же понимаешь, что в этой строчке исходя из вопроса может быть всё что угодно.